# Midi interface with good latency

Tags: audio, midi

I'd like to connect a MIDI keyboard to my PC. The keyboard doesn't have an USB interface and I'm looking some options.

There's a whole lot of MIDI-USB "cables" for like 5-10$, but from what I've googled, I can expect a whole lot of latency problems (at the very least), so I'll pass with those.

There seems to be another category of such MIDI-USB interfaces which are priced around 40-50$ and up. Can I expect that one of those will let me use the keyboard with no problems?

Or should I disregard the MIDI-USB interfaces in general and buy a new sound card instead, e.g. one with a real MIDI port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think USB based MIDI should be viable, think of how many live performance setups involve *notebooks* such as Macs, PCs running ableton or other software. Choose from good brands such as Edirol, Roland, Yamaha, Zoom...

I'd agree 5-10$ is cheap and likely a false economy.

Best answers will be on a specialist forum such as: http://www.soundonsound.com/forum the discussion group for the online and print magazine Sound On Sound, a good authority on electronic music and studio technology from the smallest studio to major facilities alike.